# How to center text in a div vertically?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I've centered my text in my `div` but I've only managed to center it horizontally by using `text-align: center`
However I'm having trouble centering the text vertically. I've tried using `vertical-align: middle;` but it didn't work

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ioiaq

the code with the text is right at the bottom of the html panel the text is "INFO"

and here's the code so far:

```
<div id="inf" style="
                     text-align:center;  
                     background-color: white; 
                     position: absolute; top:50%; left: 45%; width: 10%; height: 6%; 
                     z-index: 10;  
                     display: inline-block;">

  <a href="#"><span>INFO</span></a>
  </div>
```

any ideas?

I don't mind what code is used to fix the alignment it doesn't have to be css.

Comment: Using only CSS you could use the right combination of height and padding. Otherwise it's a JS job.

Comment: This person also had trouble with it, it'll still work though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: @leanyo martinet JS can be used

Answer (score 1):

To center a single line vertically, you can use CSS line-height whith the same value as the height value you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`line-height` with a `vertical-align: middle;` is probably the best way to go if you aren't using JS.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4sMPZ/)

HTML:

```
<div id="inf">
    <a href="#"><span>INFO</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inf { 
    text-align:center;  
    background-color: white; 
    z-index: 10;  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I don't mind if JS is used to achieve what I'm looking for :-)

Comment: JS is nice, but as a general rule i would try to stick to CSS for layout ;) I think that mr.musicman example should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS property vertical-align.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```